# GoLang project CMD command have strange behave

Tags: go

I'm working on a GoLang Project for Rosetta-API.
There is a implementation for exec.Command

Code:

```
    func StartBitcoind(ctx context.Context, configPath string, g *errgroup.Group) error {
    logger := utils.ExtractLogger(ctx, "eunod")
    cmd := exec.Command(
        "/app/eunod",
        fmt.Sprintf("--conf=%s", configPath),
    )

    stdout, err := cmd.StdoutPipe()
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }

    stderr, err := cmd.StderrPipe()
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }

    g.Go(func() error {
        return logPipe(ctx, stdout, bitcoindLogger)
    })

    g.Go(func() error {
        return logPipe(ctx, stderr, bitcoindStdErrLogger)
    })

    if err := cmd.Start(); err != nil {
        return fmt.Errorf("%w: unable to start eunod", err)
    }

    g.Go(func() error {
        <-ctx.Done()

        logger.Warnw("sending interrupt to eunod")
        return cmd.Process.Signal(os.Interrupt)
    })

    return cmd.Wait()
}
```

From now i will linked to github.

On line: https://github.com/ScArFaCe2020/rosetta-euno/blob/master/bitcoin/node.go#L68-L71 is the exec.Command.

the fmt.Sprintf("--conf=%s", configPath), Works fine.
Now i need to add --daemon inside it.

But when i change this to

```
fmt.Sprintf("--daemon --conf=%s", configPath),
```

It doesn't work.

Does anyone have a idea how i can add the --daemon?

Answer (score 1):

[exec.Command](https://pkg.go.dev/os/exec#Command) takes variadic string arguments. Its signature looks like this.

```golang
func Command(name string, arg ...string) *Cmd
```

Either pass a slice of stings followed by `...` or pass a number of strings as arguments.

In your case, you treat the whole string `--daemon --conf=/some/path` as a single argument, while you actually want to treat it as two distinct arguments.

The most simple way to solve this would be doing it like this.

```golang
cmd := exec.Command(
    "/app/eunod",
    "--daemon",
    fmt.Sprintf("--conf=%s", configPath),
)
```

You can learn more about variadic arguments here https://golangdocs.com/variadic-functions-in-golang for example.

Comment: I have try this already, and still doesn't work.

cmd := exec.Command(
        "/app/eunod",
        fmt.Sprintf("--conf=%s", configPath),
    )

is one command

Comment: what do you mean by doesnt work? Can you be more specific?

Comment: When i'm doing like:

cmd := exec.Command(
    "/app/eunod",
    "--deamon",
    fmt.Sprintf("--conf=%s", configPath),
)

Golang doesn't read the fmt.Sprintf("--conf=%s", configPath), where i'm adding the config line.

Comment: how do you know it doesnt read it?

Comment: Like in the config path i'm setting datadir to /data/eunod, but when we add the --daemon it works with the default path: /root/.eunopay.euno.conf

strange is without the --daemon the datadir is set perfect and when i'm run the project with only the --daemon its also works perfect. Now i need to combine both in 1..

Comment: well, technically like my answer and actually also in the code you have linked, this is the correct way to pass multiple arguments. Maybe it has something to do with the `/app/eunod` executbale. Did you try to run this without go, and see what happens?

Comment: @masternode, can you link documentation to that executable you are trying to run?

Comment: Yes without Go it works perfect. i can start eunod with both arguments and it works perfect.

Comment: daemon documentation is just a simple bitcoin forked daemon. (all bitcoin commands works there also). haven't any documentation ready for it. i have simple start the daemon with [code]daemon --help[/code] and this argument is writen there.